# final interface implementation not recognized from interface base list

Tags: interface, d

How can a method from the InterfaceBaseList be implemented in the current interface ? Example:

```
interface bar(T)
{
    void method1(T a);
    void method2(T a);
}

interface baz: bar!int
{
    final void method1(int a){}
}

class foo: baz
{
    this(){method1(0);}
    void method2(int a){}
}

void main()
{
    auto Foo = new foo;
    Foo.method2(0);
}
```

outputs:

```
myfile.d(xx): Error: foo interface function 'void method1(int a)'
is not implemented
```

It seems that the compiler doesnt get that `baz.method1` is actually `bar.method1`.
Note that the example illustrates that in baz, for some reasons, we know that method1 will always have the same implemtation. a baz implementer mays be down-casted as a bar (so making a dummy final method1 in bar is not possible).

Comment: add `override` to the methods that override a base class method

Comment: then I get `Error: function SpecItf.baz.method1 cannot override a non-virtual
function` bar.method1 is not considered as virtual ?

Comment: templated methods generally aren't

Comment: method1() is not a template method, though, is it? "bar" itself is a template, but bar!int.method1() isn't.

Comment: POO/TMP mess...something's not quite clear here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces can only declare virtual members without implementation, or final members with implementation.  Your code is attempting to override a virtual method with a non-virtual implementation.  Due to the nature of interfaces, you cannot actually override anything within them.  What you want instead is an abstract class.

```
abstract class baz: bar!int
{
    override void method1(int a){}
}
```

Replacing your `baz` interface with the above class will clear up the issue.

As an example of why this isn't allowed, consider this code: (Does not compile, of course!)

```
interface Root {
    int foo();
}

interface BranchA : Root {
    override int foo() { return 1; }
}

interface BranchB : Root {
    override int foo() { return 2; }
}

class C : BranchA, BranchB { }
```

What would `(new C()).foo()` return?  The result is ambiguous.  It is only acceptable to override the interface methods in a class, because unlike interfaces, you can only inherit one class at a time.

Comment: ah the diamond problem I see